# How to Upload, Download and Viewing videos using Java

Tags: video, uploading, download

I have a requirement that is, I have to develop web application. In this Website users will upload videos. Uploaded videos will be verified by the some persons(admin) and they will download verified videos. I don`t know what are the technologies I have to choose. my question is Apache server enough for this kind of requirement.

Users are very high.

Please suggest me some technologies that suites for me.

Answer (score 0):

I once used PHP running on an apache server with the [ffmpeg-php plugin](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) installed. This plugin can convert videos between practically any format.

However, after a few years the huge amount of server space and bandwidth required was too expensive to keep the service online, so consider that detail before proceeding, videos require a lot of storage space and even more bandwidth which someone must pay for.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  in this project user uploaded videos are deleted once it verified and utilized. unused data will be deleted by the admin. what are technologies are used by youtube for uploading , downloading and playing video for users.